# How can I log back into my Ubuntu Remote Desktop on Google Remote Desktop?

Tags: desktop, remote-desktop, google-chrome-headless

I created a Headless Ubuntu Server and I'm using Google Remote Desktop to access it. Unfortunately, I accidentally logged out of the account and now I'm stuck on the screen saver below. I'm unsure what the password is. I tried my pin already, but that didn't work. Is there a way to figure out what this password is? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to regain control over an Ubuntu Remote Desktop running on a Google Cloud VM after being locked out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71095699/how-to-regain-control-over-an-ubuntu-remote-desktop-running-on-a-google-cloud-vm)

Comment: I asked a duplicate of this, which received [a useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71095836/8565438). VTC this one, so people are redirected to that solution when finding this answer.