# How to regain control over an Ubuntu Remote Desktop running on a Google Cloud VM after being locked out?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, passwords, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04

Following [these instructions](https://ubuntu.com/blog/launch-ubuntu-desktop-on-google-cloud) I set up a remote desktop computer running on a Google Cloud Virtual Machine. I had a perfectly functional `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` machine controllable from my browser. I left it alone for a few minutes, and now the screen is locked:

[image]

I have not specified any password before. A simple enter does not let me in.

**How can I regain control over this machine?**

Comment: Connect via ssh to the vm. Once there log in as root (`sudo su`) and change the password of your user `passwd USER_NAME`)

Comment: Worked. Do you want to add this as an answer, or shall I?

Comment: I can do it. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect to your VM using SSH and then you log in as `root` using `sudo su`. Then you can change the password of any user using `passwd USER_NAME`

Comment: I logged in via clicking SSH on the list of my Google Cloud Virtual Machines, then used `sudo passwd USER_NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

For me none of these solutions works anymore. After trying `sudo passwd` I'm getting `passwd: Authentication token manipulation error`. Trying to resolve that from other posts I'm getting other errors. The simplest solution for me (and fastest) is just to connect to VM using SSH and run `sudo systemctl restart chrome-remote-desktop@$USER` Then like in the most of the instructions, you can check if it's running by `sudo systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop@$USER`.